# "Failed to start session" after interrupted upgrade to 14.04

Tags: upgrade, login-screen, 14.04

While upgrading to 14.04 using `sudo do-release-upgrade` my network connection was interrupted and several packages failed to upgrade.

Running `do-release-upgrade` again reported `No new releases found` but `apt-get` listed many packages "kept back", so it seemed the system was in an intermediate state. I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` which installed those packages again, then `apt-get autoremove` after which apt seemed happy.

However, after restarting I cannot log in at the GUI prompt. After entering my password the error "Failed to start session" appears in red. I am still able to log in from the command prompt, but I don't know what to do to solve or debug the GUI log in failure.

Comment: @Elliott, try `Ctrl-Alt-F1` to get a shell login prompt. Then you use `Ctrl-Alt-F7` to get back to the GUI.

Comment: This worked for me sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-session

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After issuing the following command I was able to log in again:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

I had previously removed `update-notifier` which caused some other packages to be removed, some of which it seems were necessary to successfully perform the distribution upgrade.

Comment: running this command gave me a message to run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' and this got me back on track thanks

Comment: Still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

For me the answer was in my /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf - I'd been running my 12.04 LTS in ubuntu-2d mode, had to revert back to just ubuntu and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Run a

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
```

to reconfigure your packages. Hopefully it will work. (At least for me it worked with several issued)

Comment: I have just tried this but the problem persists, unfortunately.

Comment: Note, `-a` is no longer an option for `dpkg-reconfigure`, at least as of Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: The '-a' option was removed due to too many bugs that resulted from it: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/1463672