# Ubuntu14.04 "Fails to start session"

Tags: upgrade, login, 14.04

Yesterday I upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 LTS to 14.04 using the update manager. Everything went smoothly. But when I restarted my laptop, it went till the login screen and as i entered my password, it prompted an error

> Failed to start session

I read in some blogs and even tried to use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a`, but even that failed with some errors. I feel it does not connect to the Internet through my router when I use the recovery mode.

Can someone please help me. I have lot of data in there and don't want to install a fresh copy of ubuntu 14.04. I am using a Dell Studio 1555 laptop with ATI Mobility Radeon 4500 HD graphic card.

I ran the following command

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a

Output: dpkg: error: unable to access dpkg status area: Read-only file system

Comment: Please run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and post the output inside your question.

Comment: please have a look to this question seems the same issue 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/450567/failed-to-start-session-after-interrupted-upgrade-to-14-04

Comment: Hi friends. Thank you so much :). The problem got solved using the link provided by mohtaw. Thankyou once again!!