# Unable to login after upgrading to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, updates, 14.10

Just updated to 14.10. It said update complete but with errors. I could go up to log in screen. But neither my user name nor guest session works.
 It says

> Failed to start session

And the worst part is there is no option which desktop environment I am supposed to log in. Could it be that there is no desktop environment at all ? Any solution will be great. Currently from live CD and waiting for reply.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450567/failed-to-start-session-after-interrupted-upgrade-to-14-04

Answer (score 0):

With same issues, I could simply use Alt + CTRL + F1 (terminal mode, use your ID and password to login) after reaching log in option, and get myself to install Cinnamon desktop (somehow Ubuntu Unity won't install and same with gnome 3 and flashback) using commands

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install cinnamon

Switch back to GUI mode using ALT + CTRL + F7 and use normal log in method.

> do-release-upgrade

gave the following result

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
>
> No new release found