# Failed to start session on 14.04 after installing R

Tags: 14.04, package-management

So...I was struggling to update R on ubuntu 14.04 and I think I messed something up. Adter I rebooted my computer I tried to login and got a failed to start session error. I also cannot not see my background (I had the default one). I browsed around and tried the apt-get install ubuntu-desktop method, by entering the terminal using ctr+alt+f1, but I get and unable to locate package error.

What can I do?

I am running 14.04 on a dual-boot with windows 10

Oh, and in case you where wondering: yes, I managed to update R.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Failed to start session" after interrupted upgrade to 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450567/failed-to-start-session-after-interrupted-upgrade-to-14-04)

Comment: @Martin Thornton I tried the methods described there but they didn't work :(.

Comment: Have you tried startx, on the ctl+alt+f1 tty then going back to ctl+alt+f7?  Something from xswat borked auto-login for me a while back.  Lightdm thought I was still auto-logging in and xfce thought I wasn't.

Comment: Just tried it, no luck.

Comment: Would updating to the newest version work?